# What is the algorithm to convert an adjacency matrix to a block diagonal structure?

Tags: sparse-matrix, block-decomposition

I'm a little at loss as to what my supervisor meant by the "**hierarchical block decomposition**" of a matrix, but the goal is to put a sparse symmetric a**djacency matrix into a block diagonal** structure to highlight the structure of the clusters present in the data.

*(The data captures whether the two proteins are adjacent in a molecule: if they are, the corresponding adjacency matrix has one on their row/column, otherwise zero. I sum a few of these adjacency matrices(one for each unique molecule) and divide the result by the number of molecules(to simulate the mean).*

I'm wondering how to get to the block diagonal structure from there. People over [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5486/rearrange-an-ordinary-matrix-to-block-diagonal-form) suggest scipy's reverse CM and seaborn's [heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705359/how-to-give-sns-clustermap-a-precomputed-distance-matrix) should be able to do that ostensibly, but i had no luck with either so far.
Should i go with SVD? What am i missng? 
This is what I got. Thank you kindly!

```
def construct_adjacency_matrix(clusters=dict, nomenclature_namespace=dict):

   nbrpairs  = tree2tuplearr(clusters['nbrtree'])
    dim       = len(nomenclature_namespace.items())
    keys      = list(nomenclature_namespace.keys())
    substrate = np.zeros((dim, dim))

    for pair in nbrpairs:
        if (pair[0] not in keys or pair[1] not in keys):
            pass
        else:
            substrate[nomenclature_namespace[pair[0]],
                      nomenclature_namespace[pair[1]]] = 1
    return substrate


def get_simplemean(targetgroup=str):
    targetspath = './../clusterdata/targetgroups/{}/'.format(targetgroup)
    batch       = os.listdir(targetspath)
    adjmats     = [construct_adjacency_matrix(openjson(targetspath+x), namespace) for x in batch]
    # laplacians  = []
    reduced = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: np.add(x,y), adjmats)
    reduced = np.divide(reduced, len(adjmats))
    plt.matshow(reduced)
    seaborn.clustermap(reduced)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

There is obviously certain structure in the data and in fact I already have the graphs of clusters, but how do i put into the form that resembles this below? I realize that this picture has quite a few more datapoints.

[image]

Comment: Look up the Dulmage-Mendelsohn decomposition.

Comment: @BrianBorchers He didn't say the input graph was bipartite.